# Gdaldem hillshade noisy artifacts

Tags: gdal, hillshade

Running the command:

```
gdaldem hillshade in.tif out.tif -z 30
```

I'm getting artifacts like:

[image]

[image]

and at -z 1:
[image]
How might I correct this? Here is the gdalinfo for the input GeoTiff. All dimensions should be in meters:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: in.tif
Size is 58273, 58273
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
Origin = (-20037508.339999999850988,20037508.339999999850988)
Pixel Size = (687.711576201671392,-687.711576201671392)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  lat#actual_range={-90,90}
  lat#axis=Y
  lat#long_name=latitude
  lat#standard_name=latitude
  lat#units=degrees_north
  lon#actual_range={-180,180}
  lon#axis=X
  lon#long_name=longitude
  lon#standard_name=longitude
  lon#units=degrees_east
  NC_GLOBAL#Conventions=CF-1.7
  NC_GLOBAL#GMT_version=6.0.0 [64-bit]
  NC_GLOBAL#history=grdmath SRTM15_land_masked.nc debug/polished.unmasked.grd AND = SRTM15.nc
  NC_GLOBAL#node_offset=1
  NC_GLOBAL#title=Produced by grdmath
  z#actual_range={-10997.708984375,8627}
  z#long_name=z
  z#_FillValue=nan
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-20037508.340,20037508.340) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 85d 3' 4.06"N)
Lower Left  (-20037508.340,-20037508.340) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 85d 3' 4.06"S)
Upper Right (20037508.340,20037508.340) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 85d 3' 4.06"N)
Lower Right (20037508.340,-20037508.340) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 85d 3' 4.06"S)
Center      (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) (  0d 0' 0.01"E,  0d 0' 0.01"N)
Band 1 Block=58273x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=nan
  Metadata:
    actual_range={-10997.708984375,8627}
    long_name=z
    NETCDF_VARNAME=z
    _FillValue=nan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These artifacts are actually a result of viewing the GeoTiff in QGIS (3.12), not the file. Here is an image of the GeoTiff in Photoshop:

[image]